# What is the GCP equivalent of AWS Client VPN Endpoint

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, vpc, google-vpc, google-cloud-vpn

We are moving from AWS to the GCP. I used [Client VPN Endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/clientvpn-admin/what-is.html) in AWS to get into the VPC network in the AWS. What is the alternative in GCP which I can quickly setup and get my laptop into the VPC network? If there is no exact alternative, what's the closest one and please provide instructions to set it up.

> AWS Client VPN is a managed client-based VPN service that enables you to securely access your AWS resources and resources in your on-premises network. With Client VPN, you can access your resources from any location using an OpenVPN-based VPN client.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently there is no managed product available on GCP to allow VPN connections from multiple clients to directly access resources within a VPC as Cloud VPN only supports site-to-site [connectivity](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/concepts/overview#specifications), however there is an existing [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/67478963) for this.

As an alternative a Compute Engine Instance can be used instead with OpenVPN server manually installed and configured following the OpenVPN [documentation](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/how-to/), however this would be a self managed solution.